# ios cancelling subscription after the user mapped in the app was deleted

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable, app-store-connect-api

In my app a separate app mail account was mapped for in-app subscriptions.
If the user who was made payment for subscriptions of the app was deleted by some admin or
super-admin, I need cancel the users auto-renewable subscriptions by developer side.
Is there any option for cancel the auto-renewable subscriptions by developer side programmatically?

Is there any option for cancel the auto-renewable subscriptions by developer side programmatically?

Comment: No. Only the user can cancel their subscriptions in their App Store account.